# How to permanently delete a LUKS encrypted partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption, luks

I have been using a LUKS encrypted partition as my `/home` directory on Manjaro. However, as I have to resize and move a few of my disk partitions, I would like to get rid of it. On Manjaro, I have already set up a new unencrypted `/home` partition and copied the content of the LUKS partition into it. What I want to do now is to permanently delete the LUKS partition with all its content in order to get free space on my disk; it seems impossible with GParted as it doesn't allow me to erase the encrypted partition.

Comment: If a partition is mounted, it cannot be removed. Unmount it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that one must close LUKS partition encryption in order to delete it in GParted… Issue solved.